# Using NetworkCallback instead of NetworkInfo

Tags: java, android, networking, deprecated

In [deprecated class NetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) there were methods `isConnected()` and `isConnectedOrConnecting()`. But in the class that we are recommended to use instead of deprecated NetworkInfo class we have only `onAvailable(Network network)`. As I understood we can use `onAvailable(Network network)` instead of deprecated `isConnected()` method, but what should we use instead of `isConnectedOrConnecting()`? Is there any alternative or maybe shouldn't we use it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are no alternative of  `isConnectedOrConnecting()` method in new api and there are no "connecting" state at all.